# Apple Swift version 5.3.1 (swiftlang-1200.0.41 clang-1200.0.32.8)

Tags: swift, frameworks, xcode12

We are creating a framework using Xcode and it is working fine with Xcode 12.1 but not working on Xcode 12.2 & above.

When the adopter app imports the framework file it shows the below error

The compiler that produced it, 'Apple Swift version 5.3 (swiftlang-1200.0.29.2 clang-1200.0.30.1)', may have used features that aren't supported by this compiler, 'Apple Swift version 5.3.1 (swiftlang-1200.0.41 clang-1200.0.32.8)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Build Libraries for Distribution to “Yes” in the framework’s build settings to resolve this issue

Comment: Build Libraries for Distribution is already set to “Yes”.Still, I am facing the above issue

Comment: Please try adding arm64 in excluded architectures

Comment: @Pratik did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Pratik I'm having the same issue. I tried these suggestions but it didn't work for me. Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: @DevanshiModha Hello. Did you fixed the problem? I have the same issue

Comment: @PavelVolobuev For me it worked by changing Build Libraries for Distribution to “Yes”

Do you have the exact issue? Also, can you please specify the Xcode version as well?